# Countplot error: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, debugging, plot, count

I have a problem where sns.countplot won't work. I got the names of the most popular color in each year, and with that I'm trying to plot a countplot that will show number (count) of each of those color. Something like .value_counts() but in a graph.

Here is the code that I've written:

```
most_popular_color = df_merged_full.groupby('year')[['name_cr_invp_inv']].agg({lambda color_name: color_name.value_counts().idxmax()}).reset_index()
```

and it returns this (example not full file):

[image]

Now when I try to do the countplot:

```
sns.countplot(most_popular_color['name_cr_invp_inv'],
              palette={color: color for color in most_popular_color['name_cr_invp_inv'].drop_duplicates()})
```

it returns an error: min() arg is an empty sequence.

Where is the problem, I can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it looks like you are trying to plot the number of entries with each color and map the color to the bar. For this, you just need to provide a dictionary with mapping of each color to the column value (which will be the same in this case) and use that as the palette. I have used the data you provided above and created this. As white is one of the colors, I have added a border so that you can see the bar. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
## Create dictionary with mapping of colors to the various unique entries in data
cmap = dict(zip(df_merged_full.name_cr_invp_inv.unique(), df_merged_full.name_cr_invp_inv.unique())) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots() ## To add border, we will need ax
ax=sns.countplot(x=df_merged_full.name_cr_invp_inv, palette=cmap) ## Plot with pallette=cmap
plt.setp(ax.patches, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black') ## Add border
```

[image]